# How to display a float with a maximum of 5 digits?

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, number-formatting

I have to determine, where does the period of zero's start to cut the number and I want 5 numbers after the '.'

I use following code:

```
NSString* result = [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.5f", CGFloat] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: @"0"]];
```

when I use it for example with '3.50300000' it gives me '3.503' and that's OK

But when I use the code with '0.50300000' it gives me '.503' when '0.503' is desired.

Is there anyone can help me?

Comment: How is `3.50300` -> `3.503` *okay* when you "want 5 numbers *after* the '.'"? That is, what is wrong with the 2nd case? Would `0.503` be *okay*? Or should the output be `3.50300` and `.50300`?

Comment: What does the word "cut" mean in reference to numbers?

Comment: I've flopped on the title a few times. Please add some more test cases of input and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.5f", myFloat];
for (int i = result.length; [result characterAtIndex:i - 1] == '0'; --i)
    ;
result = [result substringToIndex:i];
```

Comment: This is awful. Please don't do string formatting like this in your code. A simple string format of `@"%06.4f"` as @dasblinkenlight suggests is the correct way to, you know, format strings.

Comment: @Answerbot The asker made it clear that he wants to trim trailing zeros.  Your format string doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

It's `%N.Mf`, where N is the minimum width of the field and M is the number of decimal places after the ".".  If you always want at least one digit (possibly "0") before the decimal point and 3 digits after specify `%5.3f`.

Note that there's no way, using standard `%` formatting, to limit the presentation to ONLY 5 digits, such that 12.12345 would print at "12.12", while 1.12345 would print as "1.123".

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest; but it works.

```
NSMutableString* newResult = @"0";
NString* result = [[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.5f", CGFloat] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0"]];
if ([[result componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] count] == 1)
{
    [newResult appendString:result];
}
NSLog(@"%@",newResult);
```